# Replace illegal characters in Simulink block names

Tags: regex, matlab, simulink, alphanumeric

I have a question concerning Matlab-Simulink programming.

```
blocks = find_system(model_name, 'FindAll', 'on', 'LookUnderMasks', 'on', 'Type', 'block');

%replace all non alphanumerical characters with empty string
for i=1:length(blocks)
    regexprep(get_param(blocks(i), 'Name'), '\W*', ''); %'[^a-zA-Z_0-9]'
end
```

That is my code. I want to allow only alphanumerical chars and underscores in block names. But if i run the programm the names will not change.
The odd thing is, that if i let out the semicolon at the end of the line in the for loop, in the command window the names actually are changing...

I know the solution might be simple, but i am just not getting it right.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

When you call `regexprep(get_param(blocks(i), 'Name'), '\W*', '');` you are actually replacing the invalid characters, but you do not assign the replaced string.

If you modify the call like:

```
set_param(blocks(i), 'Name', regexprep(get_param(blocks(i), 'Name'), '\W*', ''));
```

the replaced name will be set for the block.

The whole snippet could look like:

```
blocks = find_system(model_name, 'FindAll', 'on', 'LookUnderMasks', 'on', 'Type', 'block');

for i=1:length(blocks)
    block = blocks(i);
    set_param(block, 'Name', regexprep(get_param(block, 'Name'), '\W*', ''));
end
```

Comment: Oh no :D
What a brain lag from my side.. Yeah for sure i need set_param!
Thank you, sir!